# Fetch data based on Current date in between from and to dates in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a collection in MongoDB database that has some data and would like to querying data. based on boardId, title, in which current date is between from and to dates as well to date overdue from current date. those document I want to fetch.

Sample Data

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6464c0c6f51f03d917106612"
    },
    "id": 4401800840,
    "boardId": 4401799576,
    "name": "Distribute Branded Swag to Site Crew(s)",
    "columnValues": [
        {
            "id": "timeline_1",
            "title": "Actual Timeline",
            "value": "{\"to\":\"2023-08-07\",\"from\":\"2023-08-01\",\"changed_at\":\"2023-05-02T15:15:45.669Z\"}"
        }
    ],
    "parentId": null,
    "groupName": "Construction",
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6464c0c6f51f03d917106616"
    },
    "id": 4401800551,
    "boardId": 4401799576,
    "name": "2 Week Lookahead Schedule-test",
    "columnValues": [
        {
            "id": "timeline_1",
            "title": "Actual Timeline",
            "value": "{\"to\":\"2023-05-06\",\"from\":\"2023-03 31\",\"changed_at\":\"2023-05-03T12:10:00.565Z\"}"
        }
    ],
    "parentId": null,
    "groupName": "Construction"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6464c0c6f51f03d917106617"
    },
    "id": 4401800726,
    "boardId": 4401799576,
    "name": "2 Week Lookahead Schedule",
    "columnValues": [
        {
            "id": "timeline_1",
            "title": "Actual Timeline",
            "value": "{\"to\":\"2023-06-30\",\"from\":\"2023-03-27\",\"changed_at\":\"2023-05-02T15:15:45.609Z\"}"
        }
    ],
    "parentId": null,
    "groupName": "Construction",
}
```

I used the following command to fetch data current date is between from and to dates but it did not give me any results. Not sure what am I missing. Please guide

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const currentDates = currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
const queryItem = {
  boardId: { $in: boardIds },
  groupName: "Construction",
  columnValues: {
    $elemMatch: {
      title: "Actual Timeline",
      value: {
        $elemMatch: {
          from: { $lt: currentDates },
          to: { $gt: currentDates }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
const constructionItems = await Items.find(queryItem).exec();
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://mongoplayground.net/p/yQdp403Ci3y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the data you provided in `value` seems to be of incorrect format.
The data should be like:

```
{
"_id": {
  "$oid": "6464c0c6f51f03d917106612"
},
"id": 4401800840,
"boardId": 4401799576,
"name": "Distribute Branded Swag to Site Crew(s)",
"columnValues": [
  {
    "id": "timeline_1",
    "title": "Actual Timeline",
    "value": {
        "to":"2023-12-12",
        "from":"2023-01-1",
        "changed_at":"2023-05-03T12:10:00.565Z"
    }
  }
],
"parentId": null,
"groupName": "Construction"
},
{
"_id": {
  "$oid": "6464c0c6f51f03d917106616"
},
"id": 4401800551,
"boardId": 4401799576,
"name": "2 Week Lookahead Schedule-test",
"columnValues": [
  {
    "id": "timeline_1",
    "title": "Actual Timeline",
    "value": {
        "to":"2023-05-06",
        "from":"2023-03-31",
        "changed_at":"2023-05-03T12:10:00.565Z"
    }
  }
],
"parentId": null,
"groupName": "Construction"
},
{
"_id": {
  "$oid": "6464c0c6f51f03d917106617"
},
"id": 4401800726,
"boardId": 4401799576,
"name": "2 Week Lookahead Schedule",
"columnValues": [
  {
    "id": "timeline_1",
    "title": "Actual Timeline",
    "value":{
        "to":"2023-05-06",
        "from":"2023-03-31",
        "changed_at":"2023-05-03T12:10:00.565Z"
    }
  }
],
"parentId": null,
"groupName": "Construction"
}
```

And on modify the `queryItem` to be like:

```js
const queryItem = {
    boardId: {$in: 4401799576},
    groupName: "Construction",
    "columnValues.title": "Actual Timeline",
    "columnValues.value.from": { $lt: currentDates },
    "columnValues.value.to": { $gt: currentDates },
};
```

This gives the output as follows:

```bash
Connected to MongoDB
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6464c0c6f51f03d917106612"),
    id: 4401800840,
    boardId: 4401799576,
    name: 'Distribute Branded Swag to Site Crew(s)',
    columnValues: [ [Object] ],
    parentId: null,
    groupName: 'Construction'
  }
]
```

Hope this helps